# Multiple annotations found at this line: - Referenced file contains errors

Tags: spring-mvc

Please help me in finding out what is wrong. Here are the contents of context-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">
```

Comment: Can you paste your whole content of file context-servlet.xml?

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand what exactly the problem is but I am assuming it is related to spring-mvc as it mentioned in the tag.
If you are trying to use spring-mvc then then this might help you.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">
</beans>
```

I am specifying the version of spring but you can change it according to your requirement.